# Should I use 'in the profession of manual turner' or 'as a manual turner' in this text?

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I have some question.

1. Should I use 'in the profession of manual turner' or 'as a manual
   turner' in this text?
2. Which sentence is better?

> 1. I completed my education **in the profession of manual turner** at Basic
>      Vocational School and then graduated from Technical Secondary School
>      as a technician mechanic.
> 2. I completed my education **as a manual turner** at Basic Vocational
>      School and then graduated from Technical Secondary School as a
>      technician mechanic.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is better, but it is still incorrect.

It should be,

> I completed my education **in** the profession of manual turning at a basic vocational school and then graduated from a technical secondary school as a technician mechanic.

"As" is also subtlety synonymous with "while".  The word expresses a duration of time, so when you say

> I graduated as a doctor

It literally means that you were a doctor **while** you graduated.

"As" is also used for comparison..

> Her eyes are **as** blue **as** the sky.

Comment: Also consider using the passive voice *was graduated from* since the active voice is usually reserved for the school.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I don't think that's correct.